# sort a text file based on another file excepting header

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file in which the first and second column are individuals ids and the rest are genotype information (I should mention there are TWO rows per individual). this file has a header line but only for the genotype columns, not the first and second columns for the individuals ids).

```
        SNP_1 SNP_2 SNP_3 SNP_4 SNP_5
2014TOR010  1   3 1 4 4 3 3 2 3 1
2014TOR010  1   1 1 2 4 3 3 2 4 1 
06SELI0115  1   3 1 4 4 3 3 2 3 1  
06SELI0115  1   3 1 2 4 3 2 2 3 2
2014TOR011  1   3 1 4 4 3 3 2 3 1 
2014TOR011  1   1 1 2 4 1 3 2 4 2 
....
```

I want to sort this file based on another another file:

```
head sorted.snps.txt
2014TOR011
06SELI0115
2014TOR010
```

but I want to keep the header.This is my desired out put:
head out.desired

```
      SNP_1 SNP_2 SNP_3 SNP_4 SNP_5
2014TOR011  1   3 1 4 4 3 3 2 3 1 
2014TOR011  1   1 1 2 4 1 3 2 4 2
06SELI0115  1   3 1 4 4 3 3 2 3 1  
06SELI0115  1   3 1 2 4 3 2 2 3 2
2014TOR010  1   3 1 4 4 3 3 2 3 1
2014TOR010  1   1 1 2 4 3 3 2 4 1 
....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested:

```
awk '
NR==1 { print; next }
NR==FNR { a[$1]=($1 in a ? a[$1] ORS : "") $0; next }
{ print a[$1] }
' file1 sorted.snps.txt
```